# In codeigniter library function how can call another function of the same library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
define('URL_TO_PARAM_KEY', 'x09c22f5');

class Encryption {

    protected $CI;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public static function decryptParam($url) {

        $ns1 = base64_decode($url);
        $result = $this->CI->xor_string($ns1, URL_TO_PARAM_KEY);
        return json_decode($result);
    }

    public function xor_string($string, $key) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
            $string[$i] = ($string[$i] ^ $key[$i % strlen($key)]);
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Plz help

Comment: I am getting error like this, <b>Fatal error</b>:  Using $this when not in object context in

Comment: You have the function declared as static. Remove that, or you'll need to create an instance of the class within the function, which would probably be a bit of a headache.

Comment: whenever i see `static` i think that, atleast in CI, you would be better with a helper rather than a class.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to either not use static, or to make the functions you need static as well. You probably don't want to create an instance of the class within the class. That's just a lot of overhead you don't need. You could also move all of this into a helper file (not everything in CI needs to be in a class).

```
class Encryption {

    /* not needed
    protected $CI;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }
    */

    public static function decryptParam($url) {

        $ns1 = base64_decode($url);
        $result = self::xor_string($ns1, URL_TO_PARAM_KEY);
        return json_decode($result);
    }

    public static function xor_string($string, $key) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
            $string[$i] = ($string[$i] ^ $key[$i % strlen($key)]);
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both methods belong to the same class, just replace this:

`$this->CI->xor_string($ns1, URL_TO_PARAM_KEY);`

with this:

`$this->xor_string($ns1, URL_TO_PARAM_KEY);`

Comment: totally right... didn't notice it before. `self::xor_string` then :)... that said, I agree with Alex. If you definitely need static with CI, you're better off using a helper class rather than dealing with all the overhead of static and class instantiation